# What happened to the media manger?

Tags: images, media-library

Since WP 3.5 (right?), the media manager has been "streamlined" and images are no longer, as I can see it, ordered by year / month in the media manager, although they are still saved as before.

Is there any way I can use a hook (or something) to display folders in media manager?

Comment: Now who gave me -1 and why? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is obvious: no, you can't. Why? Because there is no folders in database for media attachments, all media files are stored as single row in `wp_posts` table.

I suppose it does not really matter where your media files are stored, it could be your hosting or CDN network, somebody else hosting, etc :) So there is no logical folders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd forgotten that files are saved as posts (which I believe is not the best option). So in order to have any form for file organization, one will have to find / create a plugin?

Comment: Yes, looks like it would be the best option to use a plugin. Not sure if there exists any...